# Implementation of Erasing a particular path in Android Canvas Pain Application

Tags: android, android-canvas

I am trying to build a basic Android Canvas paint application with paint , erasing , highlight , undo / redo features. I have made each of the paths as discrete and maintaining a stack of them to implement the undo/redo feature. Now I want to implement erase where by just tapping on a particular annotation , I need to delete that. I am unable to detect that on which path the user as made a touch.

Sample implementation should be like the action memo in samsung galaxy tabs action memo .http://support-us.samsung.com/spsn/detail.jsp?ctg_id=1280&sub_ctg_id=&live_id=&video_id=2942911618001
See the delete feature of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic problem here is hit testing. The brute force way is to to store all the annotations and then for each coordinate on each annotation check for the distance and if the distance is less than some threshold then hit testing succeeds. But this is highly in efficient

After a lot of research I finally solved this problem with the following method:

1. Store all the annotations and their tap points and create a bounding
   box for each of them ([Read about bounding box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_box))
2. Now on each tap find out those annotations for which the tap target lies in the bounding box of that annotation. Mark these annotations as your candidate annotations
3. For each of the candidate annotation do the brute force testing by checking if the hit point lies near to that annotation

We can further improve our approximation of finding candidates by using a [convex-hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) instead of bounding box